# Querying a Styled Layer Descriptors file for OS MasterMap area fill data

Tags: sld, os-mastermap

I am attempting to write a software to import OS MasterMaps into our product and am having difficulty getting the area styles to import correctly.

How do I get the fill color for a combination of 
osgb:descriptiveGroup + osgb:descriptiveTerm + osgb:make?

When I look at the public domain style files Ordnance Survey provides (e.g. topographicarea-outdoor.sld) I do not find these three descriptions.

How would I determine what fill color to use for a combination of these three values? The .sld files make no reference to osgb:descriptiveGroup, osgb:descriptiveTerm, or osgb:make. All I see is a  tag with a description of the Feature Type and its  color.

For Example, the OS MasterMap (a GML format) has an entry with this information

```
 <osgb:descriptiveGroup>Tidal Water</osgb:descriptiveGroup>
 <osgb:descriptiveTerm>Foreshore</osgb:descriptiveTerm>
 <osgb:make>Natural</osgb:make>
```

My quandary is how to find out what color to fill the area by querying a Styled Layer Descriptors (SLD) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed things up there is an [SQL script](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OSMM-Topography-Layer-stylesheets/tree/master/Schema%20version%207/SQL) you must apply to the OS MasterMap data that calculates a `style_code` that is then used in the SLD to style the features.

If you want to work directly from the GML (though I wouldn't advise that) you will need to reverse engineer the [scripts](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OSMM-Topography-Layer-stylesheets/blob/master/Schema%20version%207/SQL/PostGIS/Array/topographicarea_createtable_array.sql) which are really just two long cases statements.